# Timer in Pygame

Tags: python, timer, countdown

I'm completely new to Python and I'm trying to set a timer in this game I have... Everything else has been fine but this timer is a headache.
I'll only post the parts associated with the timer to make it easier.

```
frame_count = 0
second = 0
minute = 5
hour = 1
time = "1 5. 0"
```

And then in my main loop I have.

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont('DS-Digital', 50, False, False)
text = font.render(time,True,red)
display.blit(text, [302, 50]) 

frame_count += 1  

if frame_count == 60:
    frame_count = 0
    second -= 1
elif second == 0:
    second = 9
    minute -= 1
elif minute == 0:
    minute = 9
    hour -= 1
elif second == 0 and minute == 0 and hour == 0:
    second = 0
    minute = 0
    hour = 0

hour = time[0]
minute = time[2]
second = time[5]  

clock.tick(60)
```

This gives me back an error for being wrong type but I've tried converting to int and vice versa... So frustrating...

I've looked at so many examples but most examples are actual minutes and seconds.

I need my right number to just countdown from 9 to 0 then minus off middle number and so forth.

Comment: Please, show the exact traceback which indicates the line, etc...

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing below. That's probably the issue you're assigning hour, minute,second to some character from time string

Comment: I don't know what you mean nbro. All my ridiculously incorrect code aside though guys.., All I'm trying to do is calculate the third number to control seconds from 9 down to 0, when it gets to 0, it's going to minus 1 from the 15. Can someone instead just show me the correct way to do this? That way I can learn where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this your whole code then you didn't imported pygame. (import pygame) at the begining and you should loop it all so for example:

```
import pygame
while True:
    ...
    Your code
    ...
```

Specify more your question please, I see that you should use if insted of elif because once it got to 1 1 0 it will turn to 1 0 9 and then into 0 9 9 in two frames.

```
elif second == 0 and minute == 0 and hour == 0:
    second = 0
    minute = 0
    hour = 0
```

This doesn't make sence really it's like if you calculate
if I have a = 0 then do a = 0 if you know what I mean (it does nothing).

Edit:
There is working code, you can edit it and replace your old code with it.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
red = (255, 0, 0)
bg_color = (0, 0, 0)

frame_count = 0
time = "1 5. 0"

while True:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
    frame_count += 1

    hour = int(time[0])
    minute = int(time[2])
    second = int(time[5])

    if second > 0 and frame_count == 20:
        frame_count = 0
        second -= 1
    if second == 0 and minute > 0 and frame_count == 20:
        frame_count = 0
        second = 9
        minute -= 1
    if minute == 0 and hour > 0 and frame_count == 20:
        frame_count = 0
        minute = 9
        second = 9
        hour -= 1

    time = str(hour) + " " + str(minute) + ". " + str(second)

    font = pygame.font.SysFont('DS-Digital', 50, False, False)
    text = font.render(time, True, red)
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    screen.blit(text, (302, 50)) 

    pygame.display.update()
```

I'm quite sure that there is easier solution or more pythonic one, but it works and that is most important.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys.

Brambor, that's not all my code, that's just everything related to the timer in my code.

sorry one sec, finishing comment

Comment: Brambor, that's not all my code, thats just everything related to the timer in my code. And yeah, your right, that's my problem too is trying to calculate it to correctly to control the timer using the frames for actual seconds, if it does that in two frames, that's way too quick. And I've still never got this to work without an error yet though to see that happen. And about the last elif, I put that in there so once the timer gets all the way down to 0 0 0, it will just stay at 0 0 0, not go negative. But I do see what your saying now, yeah, it's supposed to be just an if.

Comment: I'll try to explain what I'm doing again.
I have my numbers displayed on the screen with this:

   ------- time = "1 5. 0"----
   ------font = pygame.font.SysFont('DS-Digital', 50, False, False)-------
    ---text = font.render(time,True,red)---------
   --- display.blit(text, [302, 50])-------------------

Basically, I need to calculate the third number to control seconds in sets of 9, when it gets to 0, it's going to minus 1 from the 15.
Don't let my hour and minute variables confuse you, they aren't actually hours and minutes, I just labeled them that so I could differentiate the 3 numbers.

Comment: Your the greatest man! It works. The craziest thing is that I was doing everything backwards.. Every time I look at an example to learn from and compare, I'm always doing things backwards... lol

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines:

```
hour = time[0]
minute = time[2]
second = time[5]
```

it should work without them. Then ask what you are attempting to do with them

Comment: FireBlade, I'm trying to use those lines to display the calculated timer back to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign elements from time to you hour, minute, second variables convert them to an int like this:

```
hour = int(time[0])
minute = int(time[2]
second = int(time[5])
```

Comment: Moshe, thanks, I was trying to convert the wrong items I see.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for simple way to sleep at the end of each iteration for the leftover time for a desired update rate

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from time import sleep as sleep

class loop_timer():
    """ simple game loop timer that sleeps for leftover time (if any) at end of each iteration"""
    LOG_INTERVAL_SEC=10
    def __init__(self, rate_hz:float):
        ''' :param rate_hz: the target loop rate'''
        self.rate_hz=rate_hz
        self.start_loop()
        self.loop_counter=0
        self.last_log_time=0

    def start_loop(self):
        """ can be called to initialize the timer"""
        self.last_iteration_start_time=timer()

    def sleep_leftover_time(self):
        """ call at start or end of each iteration """
        now=timer()
        max_sleep=1./self.rate_hz
        leftover_time=max_sleep-(now-self.last_iteration_start_time)
        if leftover_time>0:
            sleep(leftover_time)
        self.start_loop()
        self.loop_counter+=1
        if now-self.last_log_time>self.LOG_INTERVAL_SEC:
            self.last_log_time=now
            if leftover_time>0:
                print('loop_timer slept for {:.1f}ms leftover time for desired loop interval {:.1f}ms'.format(leftover_time*1000,max_sleep*1000))
            else:
                print('loop_timer cannot achieve desired rate {}Hz, time ran over by {}ms compared with allowed time {}ms'.format(self.rate_hz, -leftover_time*1000, max_sleep*1000))
```

Use it like this

```
    looper=loop_timer(MODEL_UPDATE_RATE_HZ)
    while not self.exit:
       # do your stuff here

        try:
            looper.sleep_leftover_time()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logger.info('KeyboardInterrupt, stopping')
            self.exit=True
            continue
```